Count sections inside collected environment
Here's what I'm trying to do:
I am trying to write an environment to conditionally hide its contents if a global bool is set. Sections inside the environment should still increase the section counter, even if the environment content is hidden.
This is my attempt so far:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3, collect, xparse}

\newif\ifhidepresentation
\hidepresentationtrue

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_presentation_section_count_int

\NewDocumentCommand{\countsections}{m}
{
    \int_zero:N \l_presentation_section_count_int
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \tl_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_tl
    {
        \str_if_eq:nnT {##1} {\section} { \int_incr:N \l_presentation_section_count_int }
    }
    \int_use:N \l_presentation_section_count_int
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{presentation}{%
    \@nameuse{collectinmacro}{\presentationcollection}{}{}%
}{%
    \@nameuse{endcollectinmacro}
    % --------------------------------------------
    Number of sections in environment: \countsections{\presentationcollection} % show for testing
    % --------------------------------------------
    % Conditionally include the collected content
    \ifhidepresentation
         %\stepcounter{section}{...} % increase section counter?
    \else
        \presentationcollection%
    \fi
    \par
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
Text1
\begin{presentation}
    Text2\\
    \section{Section 2}
    Text3\\
    \section{Section 3}
    Text4\\
\end{presentation}
Text5
\section{Section 4}

\verb|\countsections{\section{}}|: \countsections{\section{}}
\end{document}

This outputs the following:

\countsections{\section{}} returns 1, but \countsections{\presentationcollection} returns 0.
How can I fix that?
Basically, I want Section 4 to have counter 4.
The reason I'm trying to count the sections instead of just evaluating the content inside a hidden box is, that I do not want any of the hidden content to affect the document, i.e. no leaps in float/equation/footnote/etc. numbering, or any other potential effects.
I also tried
\regex_count:nVN { \c{section} } \l_tmpa_tl \l_presentation_section_count_int 

which has the same problem.
I am not very familiar with L3, so I'm not sure how to pass the value of \countsections as a number to \addtocounter. Any help would be appreciated.
If someone knows a different, better approach, that would also be very welcome!

FYI: V-type arguments should always be unbraced.

@User23456234 thanks I didn't know that. Apparently N must be unbraced as well. I'll edit my post.

I managed to solve it myself using \regex_count. The problem was that I used \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_l { #1 }, but should have used \tl_set:NV, since #1 is a macro in my case.
Here is the working command if anyone ever needs this:
\NewDocumentCommand{\CountSections}{m}
{
    \int_zero:N \l_presentation_section_count_int
    \tl_if_single_token:nTF {#1} % check input type
      { \tl_set:NV \l_tmpa_tl #1 } % set token list from variable
      { \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 } } % set token list from normal input
    \regex_count:nVN 
        { \c{section} } % pattern
        \l_tmpa_tl % input string
        \l_presentation_section_count_int % output counter
    \int_add:Nn { \l_presentation_section_count_int } { \value{section} }
    \setcounter{section}{\int_use:N \l_presentation_section_count_int}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

Then it's just
\ifhidepresentation
     \CountSections{\presentationcollection}
%...


It is easier to evaluate the region but not use it in the final document.
Unrelated but never use \\  at the end of a paragraph (I left them in, but LaTeX does warn about them)

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{expl3, collect, xparse} expl3 and xparse are included in latex don't need to be loaded.

\newif\ifhidepresentation
\hidepresentationtrue


\newenvironment{presentation}
{\ifhidepresentation\setbox0\vbox\bgroup\bgroup\fi}
{\ifhidepresentation\egroup\egroup\fi}


\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
Text1
\begin{presentation}
    Text2\\% never end a paragraph with \\ Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 17--18
    \section{Section 2}
    Text3\\% Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 19--20
    \section{Section 3}
    Text4\\% Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 21--22
\end{presentation}
Text5
\section{Section 4}


\end{document}


Unfortunately if the body is evaluated, the sections, subsections etc. inside show up in the TOC, which is the reason why I am trying to just count sections and increment the section counter. Thank you for your answer though.
The \\\ were from before I inserted the sections, but underful hboxes are really not a concern in an MWE anyways...

@d8xa the toc is a minor issue, you can set \c@tocdepth=-1 inside the enviornment so it doesn't write toc entries for example. The \\  were a concern for me as I tested my answer got all the warnings and had to double check they were there before and not my fault.

My fault for not explaining my requirements. It's not just the TOC. I want none of the hidden content (except the number of sections) to affect the document. i.e. no leaps in float/equation/footnote/etc. numbering. But since your solution technically solves my original post, I'll accept your answer in a few days if no one else has a better solution.

@d8xa I am not desparate for points, no harm in clarifying the question and seeing if someone else answers, I won't adapt this answer though as this mechanism only really makes sense if you want all counters so it is what it is but someone may post a different mechanism closer to your original suggestion specifically for sections.
